# SQL - retrieve in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

If I use the normal data join

```
 select table1.Id , Column , Number from table1, table2 where
   table1.Id = table2.Id
```

It resulted:

```
  _____________
   Id  Column Number
   ab | A | 3 
   ab | A | 5 
   ab | A | 8 
   bc | B | 1
```

---

The question , how can I get three records in **table2**(group by id).
if there are not enough three records , it will show null.

There are the expected result I would like to get it without using `PL/SQL`

```
 Id  Column Number 
   ab | A | 3 
   ab | A | 5 
   ab | A | 8 
   bc | B | 1 
   bc | B | null 
   bc | B | null
```

Here is table information. 
Thank you for your helping

---

table1

```
Fields: Id,Column
data:
  ab     |   A   
  bc     |   B
```

(Id is the primary key in talbe1 and table2 have not primary key

```
table2
Fields:Id,Number
ab    |   3 
ab    |   5 
ab    |   8 
bc    |   1
```

Comment: Jeff Atwood has perhaps the definitive post on joins at http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: What about left join?

Comment: seems like an outer join.. but then i think you are not considering your data correctly.. for example? how do you know there are not 4 rows and ab is also not missing one?

Comment: I think you should apply left join. and for 'ab rows = bc rows' you should handle this from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LEFT JOIN to achieve the result

> Id | Column | Number
>
> ---
>
> ab | A          | 3
>
> ab | A          | 5
>
> ab | A          | 8
>
> bc | B          | 1
>
> bc | B          | null
>
> bc | B          | null

Use the following T-SQL statement:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.[Column], t2.Number
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id
```